# java.lang.RuntimeException:IllegalAccessException

Tags: android

logcat is showing me error

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer, PID: 30803
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer/com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.fragment.DomainRegistration}:
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessException:
>   java.lang.Class
>   is not accessible from java.lang.Class

i have included my file in manifest also

## Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="in.goodiebag.carouselpicker"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/responsive"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Splash"
            android:label="WebTechniQ">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".fragment.digital_marketing"
            android:label="Digital Marketing">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".fragment.website_designing"
            android:label="Website Design and Development">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".fragment.DomainRegistration"
            android:label="Domain Registration">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".Registration"
            android:label="Query Form">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

## DomainRegistration.java

```
  package com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.fragment;

        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.android.msahakyan.expandablenavigationdrawer.R;

    /**
     * Created by tanis on 18-06-2018.
     */

    class DomainRegistration extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
            setContentView( R.layout.domain_registration );
            ImageView imageView =  (ImageView) findViewById( R.id.imageView3 );
            final TextView helloTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView56);
            helloTextView.setText(R.string.do_2);
            final TextView helloTextView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView59);
            helloTextView1.setText(R.string.do_1);


        }
    }
```

Comment: Declare DomainRegistration in public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make it public like below:

```
public class DomainRegistration extends AppCompatActivity {
```

Hope this helps.